# Max output is incorrect

Tags: c++, random, max, min

Trying to calculate max and minimum values of random numbers in arrays, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have been trying to figure it out and I am at my wits end. Maybe one of you can help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *sora;
    int num;
    int min;
    int max;

    cout<< "Enter the size :  " ;
    cin >> num;
    cout<< endl;
    sora = new int [num];   

    max= sora[0];
    min= sora[0];

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for(int x=0;x<num; x++) {
        sora[x]=rand()%100;

        if(min > sora[x]) {
            min=sora[x];        
        }
        else if (max < sora[x]) {
            max=sora[x];
        }

        cout<< sora[x] << endl;     
    }

    cout<< "Maximum value is: " << max << endl << "Minimum value is: " << min;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised I can't immediately find a good duplicate for this question.

Comment: I know right? It seems so simple, like someone else would have made this mistake, but there aren't many who have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(min > sora[x]) {
    min=sora[x];
}
else if (max < sora[x])
{
    max=sora[x];
}
```

has the problem. The second `else if` statement is entered only if the first if is satisfied. But the second `if` has to be executed always. Please change the above block as follows

```
if(min > sora[x]) {
    min = sora[x];
}
if (max < sora[x]) {
    max = sora[x];
}
```

And you are also using an uninitialized area to compare against. If you are using only positive numbers

```
max = 0;
min = UINT_MAX;
```

If you use negative numbers also, then

```
max = INT_MIN;
min = INT_MAX;
```

You have to include `<limits.h>` for these macros.

Comment: I still get the error, the minimum value is correct but the maximum value is blown way out of proportion.

Comment: Here are the results i got just now.
Maximum value is: 2952960
Minimum value is: 25

The real maximum value is 96

Comment: did u initialize min and max properly>

Answer (score 2):

You are reading an uninitialized memory location:

```
sora = new int [num];   

max= sora[0];
min= sora[0];
```

Creating the array with `new` does not initialize its contents.

This causes what's known as undefined behavior, meaning almost anything can happen. In this case, it's probably pretty vanilla: some arbitrary value (most likely outside the 0-99 range of `rand()%100`) gets stored in min and max, very often leading to incorrect results.

Instead, do

```
// must #include <limits>

int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

or even just

```
int max = 0;
int min = 99;
```

since your range is predefined.

Comment: @AlanWatts Also note the problem pointed out by Daniel and Sakthi Kumar

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing min and max to an undefined value  when you do `max= sora[0];` and `min= sora[0];`

Also, you have an `else` where you don't necessarily want one. The first value will be both the min *and* the max.
You can start by setting `max=0` and `min=99`, and that should solve that particular problem.

Comment: You were right to point out the `else` problem (which I didn't notice after seeing the undefined behavior), but setting `min` and `max` appropriately won't fix it if the first generated value happens to be the (only instance of the) maximum.

Answer (score 2):

```
sora = new int [num];   

max= sora[0];
min= sora[0];
```

This line initializes a int array with garbage, and sets max and min to garbage values.

You have two options:

1. At start initialize max to the lowest value possible (INT_MIN) and initialize min to the highest value possible (INT_MAX).
2. First create a random value and assign it at sora[0] and initialize max and min to this value. After that initialize [1..num]